# I'm working on an Shopify app with a checkout extension and was hoping someone might have an answer to an issue thats popped up

Tags: reactjs, api, shopify, shopify-app

I am trying to display something in my extension, but only if a specific shipping rate is chosen. I'm already retrieving the shipping address the customer inputted in the checkout, but in my readings of the docs, I haven't seen anything that suggests also reading the Shipping Rate selection might be possible. Does anyone know if it is possible to detect when/which Shipping Rate a customer has selected in checkout from within a checkout extension?

I've been trying a lot of things. Ran out of options

Comment: Like an event listener? I was researching docs a while ago and didn't find anything like that. I think the scope of all actions are limited to available input/output and component so access outside is not possible.

Comment: If you hook into Checkout::ShippingMethods::RenderAfter would you not get the initially check one? And then just listen for any changes to checkout, and look for details on which shipping option may have been selected? Seems like that should work?

Comment: @DavidLazar Thank you for your time! I’ll need to see if I actually can get the initially checked one, but it doesn’t matter either way, the more important part is to be able to listen to changes in the checkout. Do you know how I can listen to those changes?

Comment: This is not currently possible but there are 2 issues that go in this direction on Github:

https://github.com/Shopify/ui-extensions/issues/406 and https://github.com/Shopify/ui-extensions/issues/504